# invert a boolean expression

Tags: javascript, language-agnostic, boolean-expression

I have some code like this

```
var a = returnsABoolean();
var b = returnsABoolean();

if (!a || !b) {

} else {
  doStuff();
}
```

How would I invert the test in the if-statement such that I can rewrite this as

```
var a = returnsABoolean();
var b = returnsABoolean();

if (someExpression) {
  doStuff();
}
```

In other words, what test should I replace `someExpression` with to preserve the existing behaviour?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws

Comment: That page appears to describe how to rewrite an expression, not how to invert one

Comment: @Georgio: Once you have your expression as `!(a&&b)` isn't it obvious that the inverse is to simply remove the `!`?

Comment: @Georgio: That's the same thing.

Answer (score 10):

You need to apply De Morgan's theorem. Which states:

```
!A || !B == !(A && B)
```

Therefore your test can be re-written as:

```
if (a && b) {
    doStuff();
}
```

---

### Why does it work?

Basically, applying De Morgan's theorem you first rewrite your statement as:

```
if ( ! (a && b) ) {

} else {
    doStuff();
}
```

Since we now want to invert `!(a&&b)` we simply remove the **not**:

```
if ( (a && b) ) {
    doStuff();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

De Morgan's law states that you can rewrite `!a || !b` as `!(a&&b)`

This also works the other way: `!a && !b` can be rewritten as `!(a||b)`

Comment: But I want to get the inverse of the expression, not rewrite it

Comment: Yes, so to invert, you just remove the inversion from the rewrite, so instead of `!(a&&b)`, it's just `(a&&b)`

Answer (score 1):

Simply assign the logical inverse of your conditional to your previous scope's "else" statement.

```
if( a && b ) { 
    doStuff();
     }
```

Comment: This answer is correct, so I'm not sure as to why it was downvoted.